# Conversion from string "x" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I get the following error when trying to create a default row in the asp.net dropdown: **Conversion from string "x" to type 'Integer' is not valid.**

- CmbSalesAgents is the drop down control.
- DefaultSalesAgent is the entity object (has values)
- x is a concatenation of a numeric value and a string

**

```
Dim DefaultSalesAgent = (From o In db.PayoutRegisters
                         Join s In db.SalesAgents On s.SalesAgentId Equals o.SalesAgentID
                         Where o.PayoutRegisterID = PayoutRegisterID
                         Select o.PayoutRegisterID, x = s.CSRName + " (" + o.PaidThruDate.ToString + ")").ToList




    If DefaultSalesAgent.Count > 0 Then
        CmbSalesAgents.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem(DefaultSalesAgent.Item("x").ToString, PayoutRegisterID))
    Else
        CmbSalesAgents.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select Sales Agent Payout Register", 0))
    End If
```

Comment: `List(of T).Item` has no overload with argument string. You should pass `Integer` instead. Use `DefaultSalesAgent.Item(0)` or just `DefaultSalesAgent(0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since DefaultSalesAgent is a list object then you should access its items through integer index not a string:

```
DefaultSalesAgent.Item(integer_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically need to insert the row based off a string value, you can replace

```
DefaultSalesAgent.Item("x")
```

With

```
DefaultSalesAgent.Item(DefaultSalesAgent.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("x")));
```

You can also use contains instead of startswith depending on your needs.  Please note this is only if you specifically need to look for strings as it's a lot more expensive than accessing an index in the list.